# Always encryption EF CORE

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is EF Core 3 still incompatible with SQL always encryption? When I add enable Column Encryption Setting=Enabled to my connection string in appsettings.json my application crashes.
I'm using EF throughout my application and switching to SQLclient is not possible to me.

Comment: See: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/11#issuecomment-493091283